# Turning a linear program into an auxiliary problem

Tags: linear-programming

I have 
maximise $$10x-2y+5z$$
s.t $$2x+y-z \le 3$$
$$-8x-2y+5z \le 2 $$
$$-x+2y-3z \ge 7$$

This becomes 
maximise $$10x-2y+5z$$
s.t $$2x+y-z +s_1= 3$$
$$-8x-2y+5z +s_2=3 2 $$
$$-x+2y-3z -s_1= 7$$

Now only the third constraint gives me an infeasible solution

So auxiliary problem is

Minimize $$-x_0$$
s.t $$2x+y-z = 3$$
$$-8x-2y+5z =3 2 $$
$$-x+2y-3z -x_0= 7$$

if I were to add an $x_0$ in the second and third constraint the most that it would do is make the algebra tedious, but theoretically it should not change the answer as I am trying to achieve $x_0$ =0 anyway, is that  correct?

Comment: HINT: By simple inspection the solution is one of the "simplex" points....

Comment: is my last statement correct, that placing $x_0$  in a constraint will at most do nothing?

Comment: Will find a feasible solution, if "auxiliary" is the qualification for the reduced problem focused on that stage...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are making this look hard.

If you have an LP in ineqality form

$Ax \leq b$, where A is m*n matrix

you add new variable for **each inequality** so that you have m new variables.

In your example, first mulitply third row by -1 so all inequalities are of the same type ( $\leq$ usually).

Then add m=3 new variables $s_1,s_2,s_3$:

$$2x+y-z +s_1= 3$$
$$-8x-2y+5z +s_2=3 2 $$
$$x-2y+3z +s_3= -7$$

And you can start simplex method right away, no neex for auxilliary LP.